# NSPredicate OR string and integer search

Tags: ios, nspredicate

I'm trying to use this predicate to filter the user model. However, when I add the integer to the format, the filter for string doesn't work anymore. Furthermore, only one of the two integer filter works ('group' filter works, but 'no' doesn't).

```
NSPredicate *predicateTemplate = [NSPredicate  predicateWithFormat:@"first_name CONTAINS[cd] %@ OR last_name CONTAINS[cd] %@ OR nickname CONTAINS[cd] %@ OR no = %i OR group == %i", searchText, searchText, searchText, value, value];
```

Model:

```
@property NSString *first_name;
@property NSString *last_name;
@property NSString *nickname;
@property NSInteger no;
@property NSInteger group;
```

The array contains multiple object with the property above and I filter the array like so:

```
_searchResults = [anArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicateTemplate]
```

Comment: post the contents of array you are trying to filter

Comment: @PratyushaTerli updated the question, not sure I understand what you meant by contents of the array, you mean structure or the real content?.

Comment: structure of dictionary in array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`no` is a reserved word and will only compare as equal to values that are equal to zero. I suggest you change your property name to something longer and more meaningful.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the `%K` expansion in the predicate to avoid such kind of collisions: `predicateWithFormat:@"%K = %i", @"no", value`.